# Drupal 8 - multisite with shared tables (user tables / all tables)?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I need to create about 20-30 Drupal8 sites on different domains. There will be similar content (difference only in details like city name, ajax calls, etc.) but also there will be a specific content like news.

I know all weakness of this idea, but anyway I think that shared tables in one database will be the best solution for this project. 
My steps:

- installing first default site (sites/default) with prefix for tables default_
- creating directory for second site (sites/second), and configuring sites.php (seconddomain.com => sites/second)
- installing second site (sites/second) with prefix for tables second_

... then I tried to use solution which is described on many sites:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database-configuration-stuff' => '[...database configuration]'
  'prefix' => array(
    'default'   => 'second_', // default prefix for second site
    'users'     => 'default_', // shared users...
    'sessions'  => 'default_',
    'role'      => 'default_',
    'authmap'   => 'default_',
  ),
);
```

but it doesn't work. I see only users from second site. Cache cleaning doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Maybe there is possibility to create multi-page solution with one shared database (not only for users but for nodes also) and create content directed to different domains from one admin console?

BTW: If there is any possibility to create sth like this using Drupal7 I can change d8 to d7.

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to make sth I was looking for you've got three options:

- you need to write your own module ;) ,
- you need to wait for "Domain Access" module for D8: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain ,
- you can also use D7 and module from URL which I provide above.

I chose 3rd option.